# AWS CloudFormation Condition using Fn::GetAtt failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a conditional block using the Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function but it is failing with below error -

"Template validation error: Template format error: Unresolved dependencies. Cannot reference resources in the Conditions block of the template."

```
My condition - 
"SomeCondition":{  
        "Fn::Equals":[  
            {  
                "Fn::GetAtt":[  
                    "CustomResource",
                    "ID"
                ]
            },
            "SOME-UUID"
        ]
    }
```

Can someone suggest a workaround for this? I wanted to use the condition to dynamically select a script in my user-data section.

Comment: What's the response of CustomResource look like?  It has `ID` in it?

Comment: @Sandeep can you able to resolve this problem ? Because i am also got struck with this thing

Answer (score 1):

The "Cannot reference resources in the Conditions block of the template" error message is explained in the [Condition Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html) documentation:

> **Note**
>
> You can only reference other conditions and values from the Parameters and Mappings sections of a template. For example, you can reference a value from an input parameter, but you cannot reference the logical ID of a resource in a condition.

As for a workaround for dynamically selecting a script in your user-data section, you could move your conditional logic from CloudFormation into your user-data script directly, e.g., using a [Bash conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) and the [`Fn::Sub` intrinsic function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html):

```
UserData:
  "Fn::Base64":
    !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      if [[ ${CustomResource.ID} == "SOME-UUID" ]]; then
        # some commands
      else
        # other commands
      fi
```

Comment: How does the bash script get the CustomResource.ID? Where does that variable get defined?

Comment: @BradEllis the `ID` attribute of the `CustomResource` resource (which is assumed to already exist by the original question) is expanded by the `!Sub` intrinsic function before it ever becomes a bash script. refer to the [`Fn::Sub` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html): "If you specify resource attributes, such as `${MyInstance.PublicIp}`, AWS CloudFormation returns the same values as if you used the `Fn::GetAtt` intrinsic function."